# Coefficients in a linearly dependent set

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

My book has given the example of the linear combination
$a_1(1,3,-4,2) + a_2(2,2,-4,0)+a_3(1,-3,2,-4)+a_4(-1,0,1,0) = 0$

and it gives a solution
$a_1=4$
 $a_2=-3$
   $a_3=2$
$a_4=0$

How would I find a solution such as this?  If I set set my vectors in a matrix and row reduce I just see that they are linearly independent without any information on coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the solutions you just write a system of equations from your vectors, one for every coordinate, since vectors are equal if and only if their coordinates (in some basis) are equal, and $0$ in this setting actually means $(0,0,0,0)$. That is, from

$$a_1(1,3,−4,2)+a_2(2,2,−4,0)+a_3(1,−3,2,−4)+a_4(−1,0,1,0)=(0,0,0,0)$$

we can go, due to product by scalars in coordinates, to

$$(a_1,3a_1,-4a_1,2a_1)+(2a_2,2a_2,-4a_2,0)+(a_3,-3a_3,2a_3,-4a_3)+(-a_4,0,a_4,0)=(0,0,0,0).$$

From this we get, due to sum of vectors in coordinates, to

$$(a_1+2a_2+a_3-a_4,3a_1+2a_2+2a_3,-4a_1-4a_2+2a_3+a_4,2a_1-4a_3)=(0,0,0,0)$$

And finally, due to equality in coordinates, we arrive to the system

$$\left\{\array{a_1+2a_2+a_3-a_4=0\\ 3a_1+2a_2+2a_3=0 \\ -4a_1-4a_2+2a_3+a_4=0\\2a_1-4a_3=0}\right\}.$$

Now, to find the solutions solve the system by any method you know of. Said solutions are the coefficients of the linear combinations of your vectors which give 0.

Of course, the matrix of this system is the same you use when row-reducing, but now you understand that you don't only want to know its rank, but want to compute its associated homogeneous solutions (i.e., its kernel).